# IE returns incomplete HTML via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

It comes down to this line:

```
jQuery.ajax(
{
    type    : "POST",
    url     : "....",
    data    : daten,
    dataType: 'html',
    success : function(response)
    { 
        jQuery('div[id="Main"]').html(response);
        ...
```

The problem ist that IE responds incomplete blocks of the "response" depending of what IE Version I use.
Like it does not return any content in  IE 8 whereas it returns like 90 % of the content in IE-9.
Interesting thing is: in IE-9 it cuts off html-code (like 10 lines) but then it goes back on.
It does not cut off completely it just randomly creates "holes" in the HTML code.

In IE 10 it works just fine ... on my machine, on others it does not.

We already tried to use append(), appendTo(), empty(), innerHtml and all that stuff but none of them worked.

Also, we are working in Demandware; so there is just the production instance, that does not show the code correcty. All other instances are working with the same code-version.

Seems like anything that is being loaded additionally makes the ajax Call go cray in IE.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Sounds like the HTML it returns is invalid. Can you show the contents of the response?

Comment: jQuery('div[id="Main"]').html(response.d); may work

Comment: Also, `div[id="Main"]` is a pretty convoluted selector. Just use `#Main`.

Comment: data :json.stringify(daten), try this

Comment: @SomnathKharat I wish you'd post those suggestions as answers so I could downvote them.

Comment: @Juhana am not confident where there are right so posted as comment..its better tthan to ans wrong ans

Comment: HTML has been checked, it's correct.
response.d does not work.
#main is not suitable to be used in demandware; that's why I am using this syntax.
Why should I stringify it when I recieve a plain text ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was a 
       <!--
 starting tag inside a javascript.
Because it was not closed but divided by \r, older IE browsers could not handle it